# Instagram access user verification before call library api

Tags: ios, instagram

i am working in Instagram IOS to post image in user wall and following https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/ for the reference. Now want to verify user before sending the post into Instagram to check same user is loggedin in instagram or not. Code is like that

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://user?username=%@",@"santanuws1123"]];

    NSLog(@"Opening: %@", instagramURL);

    if ( ![[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL] ) {
        NSLog(@"Instagram not installed, cannot open instagram url");
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
    }
```

It's not returning or validating. Also post like also not working.

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?AssetPath=%@&InstagramCaption=%@&username=%@", escapedString, escapedCaption,@"santanuws1123"]];

        // Caption is no longer supported by instagram so this url is the correct one:
        // NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?AssetPath=%@", escapedString]];

        NSLog(@"Opening: %@", instagramURL);

        if ( ![[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL] ) {
            NSLog(@"Instagram not installed, cannot open instagram url");
        } else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
        }
```

Can it possible to post in user wall sending user name??

Comment: why do you want to verify the user? Can't you just post it? I think you cant do verification with the iphone hooks

Comment: Ya , i want to verify user before posting ..

Comment: if you have the access token, you can verify using 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_self